# Locale in method Calendal.getInstance(Locale aLocale)

Tags: java, calendar, locale

What is the role of Locale in the method specified in question title? How does it affect any results? I am trying the following two lines of code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(cal.getTime().toString());
```

I receive the same result even if I try it with the parameter Locale.GERMANY or Locale.ITALY. When does it affect actually the result?

Comment: The toString() method you are calling is on the Date class.  You might try calling cal.toString() to see if you get a different result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be useful when you do calls like first day of week etc., when you do `getTime()` you may not see any difference.

As per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

> Calendar defines a locale-specific seven day week using two parameters: the first day of the week and the minimal days in first week (from 1 to 7). These numbers are taken from the locale resource data when a Calendar is constructed.

Comment: for some locales you also might get back a hindu calendar, for example, and not a gregorian one

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm going with Locale.GERMANY and Locale.ITALY having the same time.

Try comparing Locale.CANADA with Locale.GERMANY